# What does it mean that hg applies a patch to a working directory?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to use patches (to revive a corrupted repository) for the first time in my life. So I am not very well familiar with the concept, though I've read a bit. I am using TortoiseHg. I have created a patch (as a file), switched to another repository, and am trying to import it. I've asked THg to import it to Repository (other options are Shelf and Working Directory). When I click Import, THg says that the patch was imported to a working directory and the Console reads:

> % hg import --verbose --"PATH\1059.patch"
>   applying PATH\1059.patch
>   applied to working directory
>   [command completed successfully DATE]

and I don't see any changes in the history window (no revision 1059). I wonder what I should do now or what I am doing wrong.

I am on Windows 10, TortoiseHg 4.9 with Mercurial 4.9.

Comment: You said you are using THG... but the example is command line.

Comment: Sometimes there are other ways of dealing with repo corruption. It could be patches aren't your only option (maybe).

Comment: @DaveInCaz, this is the printout in THg Workbench Console (what you call Log in your answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless a better answer is provided, I have to assume that this behaviour is due to the corrupted repository: it is not observed when doing exactly the same with a non-corrupted repository.

Answer (score 0):

When something is modified in your working directory by any means, it does not automatically affect anything in your repository. You have to manually commit such a change.

For the command line `hg patch` I think the default is to commit automatically. It may be that THG is using the `--no-commit` option. You could inspect this in the THG output / log window.

For the command line, there is also this note in the help `import` ...

> first applies changes to the working directory (unless --bypass is
>       specified), import will abort if there are outstanding changes.

The THG Import window looks like this:

[image]

According to [the docs](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/patches.html#import-patches)

> You have the choice of importing directly into the repository, the
>   working folder, a shelf file, or your patch queue.

I think if you inspect the "patches will be imported to" dropdown, it may be set to "working directory" or similar. If you change it to "Repository" I think it will commit for you.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have seen the 3 options and selected Repository. Besides, after the patch is "applied", nothing seems to have changed _at all_, the directory is in the clean state with no changes to commit.