# How to understand why hg import --exact fails

Tags: mercurial

I have created a patch file (using TortoiseHg) from a single commit (changeset) from a repository and am trying to apply it to another repository.

When I do simply `hg import 1059.patch`, I get

> applying 1059.patch 
>   applied to working directory

(And I am not sure what it means. I asked [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655699/what-does-it-mean-that-hg-applies-a-patch-to-a-working-directory) about it.)

But since I want to make sure the hash value is preserved, I have used `hg import 1059.patch --exact`, in which case I get

> applying 1059.patch
>   abort: patch is damaged or loses information

How do I debug this? Can I get more info on what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: How did you generate the patch? Were there any errors or other useful output?

Comment: @DaveInCaz, I used THg, there were no errors. Just "created" and the file appeared where I asked to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you have multiple patches in a single patch file.

According to [this forum post](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/hg-export-import-problem-td795093.html):

> Import does one commit per input file and you can't exactly preserve
>   [multiple]  commit ids in one commit.

(post by Matt Mackall, who was I believe one of the HG creators / maintainers).

<sub>(FYI I searched for the error message "abort: patch is damaged or loses information" which is not common and led to that post.)</sub>

Comment: I created a patch from a single changeset 1059. Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this.  In my case, an `import --exact` failed because it was a graft and the "extra" meta data (visible with `hg log --debug`) caused a different changeset hash.  Specifically for a graft, the meta data is viewed with `hg log --debug` with the following extra line:

```
extra:       source=acdaed39eb57d8bc2efe6a6bf3547bb6d06fe2d5
```

This data is one of the inputs used by mercurial to compute the changeset hash.  But `export` does not provide that information (as of mercurial 5.2.1 at least).

There are other operations that produces "extra" metadata (e.g., `rebase`).

To me this seems like a real bug - `export` does not provide "extra" data.  Of course, if `export` learns to provide that data, `import` would need to be taught how to use the extra data.

## Steps to reproduce:

```
hg init foo
(
echo "create a few changesets (with a branch) in repo foo"
cd foo
echo 0 > x
hg ci -Am0
echo 1 > x
hg ci -m1
hg up 0
echo 0a > x
hg ci -m0a
)
echo "clone the 3 changesets in foo to foo2"
hg clone -U foo foo2
(
echo "add a couple more changesets to foo, the second of which is a graft"
cd foo
echo 2 > x
hg ci -m2
hg up -r1
hg graft --log 2
echo 0a > x
hg resolve -m x
hg graft --continue
hg export 3 > exp3
hg export 4 > exp4
echo "log of the two new changesets:"
hg log -G --debug -r3:4 | cat
)
(
echo "import --exact the two new changesets from foo to foo2 (or try to)"
cd foo2
hg log -G --debug | cat
echo "import the first new changeset - this will work fine"
hg import --exact ../foo/exp3
hg log -G --debug -r3 | cat

echo "this will fail - presumably because of the extra graft metadata in rev 4"
hg import --exact ../foo/exp4
)
```

This does not answer the OP's first question about how to debug this, but it is a conjecture about what is going wrong (second question).

## Update:

Indeed this has been discovered and logged as a bug:

https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4857

Unfortunately, it was not fixed.